How to set keyboard shortcut to insert a timestamp (time & date) in KWrite?
KWrite is included as the default text editor in several popular Linux distros (such as Fedora KDE).
Inserting a timestamp is a basic feature of text editors.
How can one set a keyboard shortcut to insert a timestamp (time and date) in KWrite?
It seems like it should be obvious, but I've gone through all the settings, read the small amount of documentation that exists, performed numerous searches, and even asked AI chatbots.  Nothing had a solution (except AI, of course, which offered multiple solutions that weren't possible, which was a big waste of time).
If I can have a choice of the formatting, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM is preferred.

If you are willing to change your clipboard manager to copyq, then here is a discussion about how to do that:   https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/387.  Copyq is my fav clipboard manager, and likely copyq can replace whatever you are using w/o losing any features.
And this task can be also done with a Kate plug-in; Kate is much more powerful than Kwrite.
You cannot change Kwrite to fit your expectations, but you can change tools to get the desired workflow with these two ways, at least.

Thanks for your answer.  Unless someone else finds a way to do this in KWrite, I think this is a very good answer.  It nicely says "there is no way to do it", and then is helpful in providing a tool and an alternative.  I am still hopeful that maybe someone knows a way to do it directly in KWrite (so bizarre that it doesn't have this built-in, and that even Kate requires a plug-in for something so basic).  BTW, I've used CopyQ, and it is excellent.  I'm not sure how it will work with KDE Plasma, as other system tray apps don't seem to be able to add themselves to the tray.
